# Ruby on Rails Inflection error - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails to create a website for a game I play.

I have a `User` model and a `Starbase` model. The relationship I am trying to setup is like so

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :starbases
end

class Starbase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

However when I open script/console and try to access the users starbases it gives me an error: `NameError: uninitialized constant User::Starbasis`.

It seems as if it is a problem with inflection and rails is not pluralizing starbase correct.

I have tried adding this to the inflections.rb in the intializers folder:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'starbase', 'starbases'
end
```

but it still does not solve the issue. Could anyone give advice on how to get this working?

Comment: Not sure, but doesn't this change require a server restart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried adding a line for the inverse inflection (i.e. 'singular'):

```
 inflect.singular "starbases", "starbase"
```

I tried your example in my console and it was the singularization that caused problems, not the other way around. I'm not sure if this fixes other issues (like routes), but it should fix the simple stuff (I think).

Comment: Hey, I have tried this but unfortunately I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Hey, I got it working with inflect.irregular "starbase", "starbases".  Marking your question as correct.  Cheers for the response.

Comment: That was my next suggestion, but it worked on my setup as I proposed so didn't want to confuse the issue. Nice work...

Comment: Great! Was just banging my head against the wall with another model name (Tax -> Taxes -> Taxis). Using `inflect.singular` didn't work, but `inflect.irregular` did.

Answer (score 0):

Little trick i picked up to double check how Active Support might singularize, or pluralize my Class names, and/or Module names.

have your rails app server running and in a new tab enter into your rails console by typing `rails console`. In there you can easily double check for the correct style for your names.

*long way* `ActiveSupport::Inflector.pluralize "fish"`
`# => "fish"`

*short way* `"fish".pluralize`
`# => "fish"`

You can find more examples here

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/test/inflector_test_cases.rb